# Transitivity of a binary relation

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Given: The domain of the relation $R$ is $\{a, b, c, d\}.$ $R = \{(a, b), (b, a), (c, d), (d, c)\}.$

Why is this relation not transitive? According to my textbook,

By definition

> R is transitive if and only if for **every three elements**, x, y, z ∈ A,
>   if xRy and yRz, then it must also be the case that xRz.

and R is not transitive when

> The situation that is not allowed in a transitive relation is for
>   there to be an x, y, and z , such that xRy and yRz are true but xRz is
>   not true. Notice that the definition of transitive is a universal
>   statement. If any x, y, and z in the domain have the forbidden pattern
>   of xRy and yRz but not xRz, then the relation is not transitive. If
>   there is no **triple** x, y, and z that has the forbidden pattern, then
>   the relation is transitive.

I thought it was transitive because it says "for every **three elements**", if $xRy$ and $yRz$ then $xRz$. Since there are no **three** elements where the situation $xRy$ and $yRz$ even occurs, I assumed it would be considered transitive.

Furthermore, the second excerpt states that "If there is no **triple** x, y, and z that has the forbidden pattern, then the relation is transitive." And as far as I can see, there is no **triple**, with the forbidden pattern.

I am confused.

Comment: It's NOT transitive, because you have $a\,R\,b$ and $b\,R\,a,$ and by transitivity that implies $a\,R\,a.$ But $a\,R\,a$ is not true.

Comment: sorry, i meant to ask why is it NOT transitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the definition does **not** say "for every three **distinct** elements". In the given example, with $x:=a$, $y:=b$, and $z:=a$, we see that $xRy$ and $yRz$, but not $xRz$ (i.e., $aRb$ and $bRa$, but not $aRa$).

Comment: doesn't "triple" imply 3 distinct elements?

Comment: @mathguy No.  $<a,b,a>$ would be considered a triple.  Anyway, I think this is a good example of how the language of logic can avoid the ambiguities of natural language.

Answer (score 1):

It's **not** transitive, because you have $a\,R\,b$ and $b\,R\,a,$ and by transitivity that implies $a\,R\,a.$ But $a\,R\,a$ is not true.